# Error during linking using makefiles: Ubuntu

Tags: c, linker, makefile, ubuntu-12.04, gnu-make

I have the following two projects:

```
`/home/jagbirs/Downloads/sample/SampleExtLib1` containing: 

ext_lib1.c
ext_lib1.h
Makefile
```

`/home/jagbirs/Downloads/sample/SampleMakeTest` containing:

```
main.c
Makefile
```

I am learning how to link external libraries. There is a function in ext_lib1.h which I am

using in main.c but I get the following error after make:

```
gcc -o main main.c -L/home/jagbirs/Downloads/sample/SampleExtLib1 -lext_lib1 
main.c:10:22: fatal error: ext_lib1.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The two makefiles are as follows: 
SampleMakeTest/Makefile:

```
LIB = main
SRC := main.c
CFLAGS := -I../SampleExtLib1

all: $(SRC)
    gcc -o $(LIB) $(SRC) -L/home/jagbirs/Downloads/sample/SampleExtLib1 -lext_lib1 

clean: 
    rm -f *.o
```

SampleExtLib1/Makefile:

```
all: ext_lib1.o
    ar r libext_lib1.a ext_lib1.o

clean: 
    rm -f *.o *.a
```

could some please help me figure out why the linking is not happening properly?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add `-I` to include the `.h` file of the library:

```
gcc -o $(LIB) $(SRC) -I/home/jagbirs/Downloads/sample/SampleExtLib1 -L/home/jagbirs/Downloads/sample/SampleExtLib1 -lext_lib1
```

Comment: this is working but the point is that why am I having to include the header file also when I have created the archive for the external library and trying to link it over here?

Comment: Yes, headers are shared between a library and a project which depends on the library, since headers contain the _contract_ or interfaces of the library. If you want to link to a default library in Debian-based systems, you will most likely install the `lib<name>-dev` package, which contains the header files. While `lib<name>` packages contain only the shared libraries (binaries).

Comment: I removed the #include "ext_lib1.h" from main.c and then everything compiled, linked and ran fine. Correct me if I am wrong but if I have linked a shared library then I do not need to explicitly include the header file as the functions are picked directly from the shared library. This is what I have observed. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If you call a function `ext_funct()` from `main.c`, there must be a definition for this function somewhere, either in `main.c` or an included header file. Otherwise the compilation phase will fail. But hard to guess why it works, without your source.

Comment: @nif: wrong, there must be a *declaration* (i.e. prototype) for the function in the header, but the *definition* is the actual implementation and it's the **linker** demanding it.

Comment: Sorry, I meant declaration. I tried to replay what Sunny did and it's correct that a _declaration_ / prototype is not necessary, as it's explicitly given by the _definition_ when linking statically. So thanks for correction, I take back what I said in my last comment.